# How to fix a text out of the lower margin?

Tags: floats, margins, output

I was reading my text and found a part of the text out of the lower margin. I tried to remove `[h]` from all the floats, however the result still being a part out of the margins. Any help?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe,%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
%%
\blindtext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
\subsection{Subsection}%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\par%
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{Table}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\midrule
\textbf{Head}   & \textbf{Head} \\
\midrule
CUR                     & \SI{20}{psi} \\
GS1                     & \SI{40}{psi} \\
GS2                     & \SI{40}{psi} \\
GS3                     & \SI{5000}{\volt} \\
GS4                     & \SI{450}{\degreeCelsius} \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=9.7cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\caption{Caption}%
\label{tab:param-otimizados-transi}%
\\
\midrule
\textbf{Text\newline(m/z)} &
\textbf{Text\newline(m/z)} &
\textbf{Text\newline(\si{\volt})} &
\textbf{Text\newline(\si{e\volt})} &
\textbf{Text\newline(\si{\volt})} \\%
\midrule
100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}%
%
This is the text out of the margins\par% 
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: problem is use of `ltablex`, which combine `longtable` and `tabularx`. so it seems that `tabularx` regardless that it isin `table`  float behave as `longtable` starting where start float `table`. if you remove `keepXColumns` and replace `ltablex` with `tabularx`, table will move to the next page. so, the question is, do you use `ltablex` for some long table in `tabularx` environment ...

Comment: One can also fix the problem by losing `\linespread` (even using more text for force a page 3).  Also, IIRC one shouldni't create floats (even non-floating floats) in the middle of paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. How about you use the `float` package and set the alignment of the last table to `H` instead of `h`.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}% added
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe,%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}

\section{Section}
%%
\blindtext Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
\subsection{Subsection}%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.\par%
%
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{Table}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\midrule
\textbf{Head}   & \textbf{Head} \\
\midrule
CUR                     & \SI{20}{psi} \\
GS1                     & \SI{40}{psi} \\
GS2                     & \SI{40}{psi} \\
GS3                     & \SI{5000}{\volt} \\
GS4                     & \SI{450}{\degreeCelsius} \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%
%
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\par%
%
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=9.7cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{table}[H]%changed this to upper case H.
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*5{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\caption{Caption}%
\label{tab:param-otimizados-transi}%
\\
\midrule
\textbf{Text\newline(m/z)} &
\textbf{Text\newline(m/z)} &
\textbf{Text\newline(\si{\volt})} &
\textbf{Text\newline(\si{e\volt})} &
\textbf{Text\newline(\si{\volt})} \\%
\midrule
100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}%
%
This is the text out of the margins\par% 
%
\end{document}
```